# Loading linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

how to resolve this loading kernel errors of version magic '5.15.0-94-generic' SMP mod_unload modversions should be '5.4.0..26-genric' SMP mod unload.
I try to load my kernel code to kernel but it gives error related mismatch version of something like magic version

Comment: It seems that your running kernel is `5.4.0..26-generic`, but you build a kernel module against version `5.15.0-94-generic`. You need to build a kernel module against the kernel which you are running.

Answer (score 0):

your kernel activated module signature.
you have two option :

1. recompile module for new kernel .
2. enter `make menuconfig` disable module signature , then compile kernel and load your module .